# Jenkins Parameterized Remote Trigger Plugin Returning the Status of the Wrong Build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using the *Parameterized Remote Trigger Plugin* in Jenkins to kick off a remote job, but it returns the status of a build besides the one that it kicked off. I have the trigger step blocking until the remote build is finished, so it is also causing it to return prematurely, since in some cases it returns the status of a build that has already finished.

Since seeing this error, I have selected the option for the trigger step to wait until no builds are running. This should prevent the trigger step from returning the status of a build that is already running, which was part of the problem, but it has also happened when no builds were running.

The console output below is from a build where the remote job was not currently running:

```
Triggering this remote job: <job name>
Not checking if the remote job <job name> is building.
Triggering remote job now.
Remote Jenkins server returned empty response or invalid JSON - but we can still proceed with the remote build.
Checking parameters of #55
Remote Jenkins server returned empty response or invalid JSON - but we can still proceed with the remote build.
Query failed.
Checking parameters of #54
Param <param> doesn't match!
Checking parameters of #56
Remote Jenkins server returned empty response or invalid JSON - but we can still proceed with the remote build.
Query failed.
Checking parameters of #53
This job is build #[53] on the remote server.
Blocking local job until remote job completes
Remote build started!
Remote build finished with status SUCCESS.
```

So my question is essentially how can I prevent this from happening? I haven't found anything online resembling this issue, so any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is a known issue.  See the following:

- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32462
- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29222